# SearchDialog (API < 11) in the SupportActionBar

Tags: android

Taken from the [official](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) source :

> Note: If your app uses the action bar, then you should not use the
>   search dialog for your search interface. Instead, use the search
>   widget as a collapsible view in the action bar.

The problem is i use `SupportActionBar` from `v7` with minimum SDK 10 (Gingerbread). Is it possible for my apps to implement the `SearchDialog` **inside** the `SupportActionBar`?

The `SearchView/search widget` is not an option because it has minimum SDK 11 (Honeycomb).

Please help me because i want my apps to support SDK 10 with a `SearchDialog` inside the `SupportActionBar`, i need both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the AppCompat library and the support action bar, you can use the [support SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html) to make a search interface with a SearchView that works on v7+ devices.

Note as of AppCompat v21, you must use [MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionProvider(android.view.MenuItem)) to retrieve a reference to the `SearchView` rather than using `getActionProvider()` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its funny the doc said we cant

Comment: Yeah I think that document was written before AppCompat was even created, so it only lists what can be done with the standard SDK. Obviously things have advanced since then.